# How to unwrap Dictionary in extension as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>

Tags: swift, dictionary, casting, swift-extensions

I'm trying to unwrap dictionary in extension as Dictionary.
But I'm having some problems and can't find answer anywhere.

I have a function which gets a dictionary, where inside I want to get a json string from JSON dictionary, of course if it is a valid JSON object:

```
// My Function
func foo(dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) {
    let jsonString = dict.jsonString    // <-- 'String' is not a subtype of 'NSObject'
}

// My Extension
extension Dictionary where Key: NSObject, Value: AnyObject {
    var jsonString: String? {
        if let dict = self as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            do {
                let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self as Dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
                if let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    return string
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

But problem is that I have a `var dict: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`.

I also tried using `StringLiteralConvertible`

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
    var jsonString: String? {
        if let dict = self as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {    // <-- 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' is not convertible to 'Dictionary<String, AnyObject>'
            do {
                let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self as Dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)    // <-- Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' to type 'Dictionary<_, _>' in coercion
                if let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    return string
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

But then I get two errors.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I just updated my question, hope it is more clear?

Comment: why don't you change NSObject to String

Answer (score 1):

I understood from your question that you want to add some feature (do additional job) when your dictionaries' keys are `String`, and the values are `AnyObject`

You can use extension (exactly as you did in the question)

```
extension Dictionary where Key: String, Value: AnyObject {

// do what ever you want, you have the self object here
}
```

using the `self`, you can do whatever

#### After your update:

You can change the NSObject to String. This is a screenshot from my machine:

[image]

#### Update 2

Would this be good for you ?

```
extension Dictionary {
    var jsonString: String? {

        for (key, value) in self{
            if let isKey = key as? String {
                // do whatever you want
                return "Forza Roma"
            }else {
                return nil
            }

        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: You will get an error ```type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'```

Comment: @Jonauz check more please, it is working with me without errors. Show your code

Comment: I keep getting that error when I try to compile/build using your approach. It's something to do with protocols.

Comment: @Jonauz why don't you change NSObject to String

Comment: As I already said two times, it gives an error ```type 'Key' constrained to non-protocol type 'String'```. For reference, I'm using latest Xcode 7.1. Not sure how can it work for you. You could change String to StringLiteralConvertible, but in my case it still doesn't work, gives other two errors.

Comment: @Jonauz i don't know why you are getting that error. I updated my question with a screenshot from my machine. As you see, no errors ...

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Open the debug area of your Playground, you'll see the error message.

Comment: Well, I definitely tried your suggestions multiple times, even before writing this questions. But I can't compile/build project, as it gives errors. I wish that this could work.

Comment: @Jonauz now i see your point, please could you remind me with what you are trying to achieve, i kind of lost

Comment: I have a Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, and I want to get a stringified JSON using extensions.

Comment: @Jonauz okay i am trying

Comment: I might have found an answer, but want to test before posting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93190/discussion-between-jonauz-and-william-kinaan).

Answer (score 0):

I found such answer, tested and it worked. Would be interesting to hear if anyone know some other issues with this approach.
I have converted `self` to `AnyObject` and then to `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`. It seams to be acceptable.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
    var jsonString: String? {
        if let dict = (self as? AnyObject) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            do {
                let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
                if let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    return string
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

It would also work if you do `(self as? NSObject) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`.

Most likely you can remove conversion to `Disctionary<String, AnyObject>`, like this:

```
extension Dictionary where Key: StringLiteralConvertible, Value: AnyObject {
    var jsonString: String? {
        do {
            let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self as! AnyObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
            if let string = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                return string
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```